# Chrome plug-in not focusing on new tab

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm sorry if this is really basic, but I am new to writing plugins for Chrome (this is my first try) and js in general.

I am writing a plugin where I have a database I'm logged into and each entry of the database has a link and a delete button. The plugin is to visit each link and if there is a text match on the entry's link page, it deletes the entry from the database by "clicking" the entry's corresponding delete button.

The plugin is currently able to open an entry's link, but "nothing" is happening. The focused tab, at this point, is on the entry's link. My code was initially supposed to refocus on my database tab, but this is not happening. I changed the code to close the entry's link tab (which is what I want it to do anyway) and thereby refocus on my database tab. However, this is not happening either.
Here is my code:

```
// Check if page contains the text "Maternal side"
function checkPage(url, element, callback) {
  let newTab = window.open(url, "_blank");

  newTab.addEventListener("load", function onTabLoad() {
    newTab.removeEventListener("load", onTabLoad);

    let isMaternal = newTab.document.body.textContent.includes("Maternal side");

    callback(isMaternal, element, newTab);
  });
}

window.addEventListener("load", (event) => {
  // Select all 'a' elements
  let links = document.querySelectorAll("a");

  // Filter to only those with href starting with 'http://somewebsite.com/' and containing '/match/'
  let matches = Array.from(links).filter(
    (link) =>
      link.href.startsWith("http://somewebsite.com/") &&
      link.href.includes("/match/")
  );

  // Iterate over each match
  let i = 0;

  function openNextTab() {
    if (i < matches.length) {
      let match = matches[i];

      // Create a delay so things don't go nuts
      let delay = Math.random() * 8000;

      checkPage(match.href, match, function (isMaternal, element, newTab) {
        if (isMaternal) {
          newTab.close(); // Close the match tab

          let databaseTab = window.open("https://melaniesdatabase.com/something.aspx");
          databaseTab.focus(); // Focus on the database tab

          // Locate the delete button associated with this element and click it
          let deleteButton = element.parentNode.querySelector(
            'input[title="Delete"]'
          );
          if (deleteButton) {
            deleteButton.click();
          }
        } else {
          newTab.close(); // Close the match tab
        }

        i++;
        setTimeout(openNextTab, delay);
      });
    }
  }

  openNextTab();
});
```

All delete buttons on the database page currently have the same selector in my code. I'm not seeing any programmatic difference between the delete buttons other than which line they're on. I don't see how this could be causing the above issue, though.

Comment: Please clarify where this code runs because extensions have many contexts. Note that the popup is a separate window so it has its own separate devtools: right-click inside the popup and select "inspect" in the menu.